# Can't add selectonHandler to TabPanel in Gwt

Tags: java, gwt

```
SelectionHandler<Widget> handler = new SelectionHandler<Widget>() {
     @Override
     public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Widget> event) {
         TabPanel panel = (TabPanel) event.getSource();
         Widget w = event.getSelectedItem();
     }
};
TabPanel content = new TabPanel();
content.addSelectionHandler(handler);
content.add(vpanel, "Normal");

widget = new VerticalPanel();
widget.setSpacing(10);
widget.add(content);
```

> addSelectionHandler com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionHandler>java.lang.Integer> can not be applied to com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectionHandler` needs to be of type `Integer`, not `Widget` (see [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html#addSelectionHandler(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionHandler))). It should look like this:

```
TabPanel panel = ...;

panel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event)
    {

    }
});
```

or

```
TabPanel panel = ...;

SelectionHandler<Integer> handler = new SelectionHandler<Integer>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event)
    {

    }
};

panel.addSelectionHandler(handler);
```